# Separate list of string values with a comma but not the last item using StringFormat in XAML .NET MAUI

Tags: xaml, string-formatting, maui

I want to separate list of string values with a comma but not the last item using StringFormat in XAML .NET MAUI. To place a comma between each item, I will set the StringFormat as follow (this is a sample code):

```
 <Label  Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='{0} ,' }"/>
```

But how can I avoid having the comma after the last item?

Comment: Do you only want to do this through XAML? Because that is not going to work for what you want to do.

Comment: Yes i want to do it in XAML.

Comment: With XAML only this is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done only in the code behind.